# How to preview Ppt files within the app in react native

Tags: react-native

using reactnative-webview preview of ppt links Working good in IOS and in android not working its downloading the file preview not availble and i also emmbeded google docs url also not working in android please help me

Comment: sabarikobagapu can you specify what problem you face while downloading the file.

Comment: @sakshimalik my problem is i am not downloading any file i just preview the URL in webview its working fine IOS but not working in android in android its automatically downlaod

Comment: Please provide your source code to better help you

Comment: <WebView 
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                allowFileAccess={true}
                allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true} 
                source={{ uri: contentsUrl }} />

Comment: https:/attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/42ef4a1a-d127-11ec-af1b-624cafbf3e7e?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential= ''request&X-Amz-Date=20220606T123000Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=AEaDDMzMjEwMDUzMjQ5NyIMw9Py1%2BmKUXktXan7KpYE6JS%2BtYt%